# NSString to expected argument NSData

Tags: swift, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I have this code:

```
 let urls : String = Baseurl+"lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&APPID="+apiKey

        if let url = NSURL(string: urls) {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: nil)

                do {
                    if let jsonRes = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonResult, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print(jsonRes)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```

But there is an error on this line: `if let jsonRes = try...`. The error is: `cannot convert value of type 'NSString' to expected argument type 'NSData'`.

When I print the jsonResult I get this:

```
{

    "coord":{
        "lon":-0.13,
        "lat":51.51
    },
    "weather":[
        {
            "id":501,
            "main":"Rain",
            "description":"moderate rain",
            "icon":"10d"
        }
    ],
    "base":"stations",
    "main":{
        "temp":284.46,
        "pressure":1023,
        "humidity":76,
        "temp_min":283.15,
        "temp_max":285.15
    },
    "visibility":10000,
    "wind":{
        "speed":7.7,
        "deg":220
    },
    "clouds":{
        "all":75
    },
    "dt":1449755400,
    "sys":{
        "type":1,
        "id":5093,
        "message":0.0414,
        "country":"GB",
        "sunrise":1449734113,
        "sunset":1449762690
    },
    "id":2643743,
    "name":"London",
    "cod":200

}
```

How can I acces those values?

Answer (score 3):

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` expects an `NSData` object, not a `String`.

Replace

```
let jsonResult = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: nil)
```

with

```
let jsonResult = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
```

and remove the try.

I should also note that this isn't really the best way to make a web request, you should use `NSURLSession` to make an async request:

```
NSURLSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urls)!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
            print(dict)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Please use `if let data = data {` instead of `if (data != nil) {` so that you can avoid the force unwrap of data. Better example for others (your code will work but unnecessary force unwrap).

Comment: Revised to make code more "Swift-y."  This was just a quick example I set up.

Comment: Cool, sorry to be be picky but beginners may learn from examples here and the extra characters were minimal. I think there is a typo/copy and paste error though with the double opening brace after the `if let`. Can you check?

Comment: Fixed the bracket typo.